# Canvas (fabricjs) block web browser zooming and moving on mobiles

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas, webbrowser-control, fabricjs

In mobile version of web browser (android default, firefox, safari, chorome etc.)

I don't know why I can't move screen when I touch canvas area.

The problem is also with zooming. If I start zoom outside the canvas and continue oferr the canvas it is ok. But when I start zooming browser window on canvas it doesn't work.

Does someone know this problem?

Oh, I forget... Simple example:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/arrowman/cts831tg/3/`
```

Comment: Sorry fo these "`" but Stackoverflow has error and I must do this to send this message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allowTouchScrolling: true` is the setting you're after.

This should be initialized when you create your canvas within the arguments in the second parameter.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('your-canvas-id', {
    backgroundColor : '#000',
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    allowTouchScrolling: true, // <-- this is what you're after
});
```

Comment: I have being using FabricJS for sometime, so I was assuming you could just set canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true; after you had created the canvas. NO. allowTouchScrolling must be set when you create the instance, like the above answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. It is:

```
canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true;
```

Bests,
A.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. You must set it using the 2nd argument of the constructor.  See @domdambrogia answer below for the correct way.  This works correctly for me.

Comment: There is no messages below, I think you was thinking about post above.
I changed post marking as "Solution" from my post to post above.
I hope you are right, I am not able to test it now :-)